# Ubuntu 18.4: Cant access bashrc anymore

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bashrc

For the first time I accessed the bashrc file. I wanted to create alias shortcuts.

I wasn't able to do anything and when I closed the terminal, I am not able to access it anymore.

It gives me the following:

```
    # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(3) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it by replacing your broken `.bashrc` with default `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel` directory:

- Switch to tty3 by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
- Log in as root
- `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/youruser/`
- `chown youruser:youruser /home/youruser/.bashrc`

Comment: Hey Gryu,
I really appreciate the reply. Please note that I am a complete noob and you will have to dumb it down a bit for me, as I got an error: 'login incorrect' / 
I wrote: 'cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/ficho/' as soon as tty3 was initiated... 

I guess im missing something on the second step:  'Log in as root'

when I access tty3 stands:
'ficho-PS63-Modern-8M login:'

Comment: Use root as login: `ficho-PS63-Modern-8M login: root`, and also provide password for root, not for ficho user. Your typing will be invisible.